# Proof of Unique Solution for Modular Exponentiation In Cryptography

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The question is about the encryption equation in asymmetric encryption.

For $c\equiv m^e\bmod n$, prove that for every unique $m$ there is a unique $c$.

Here $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes larger than $m$ and
the exponent $e$, is $\geq3$ and coprime with $p-1$ and $q-1$.

Thanks!

Comment: The condition that $p$ and $q$ be larger than $m$ is very unusual! Are you sure you have that right?

Comment: @TonyK I am not sure. It was an assumption I made considering that $n = pq$ is a very large number in practical cryptography, and that it may be necessary for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If ${\rm GCD}(e,(p-1)(q-1))={\rm GCD}(e,\phi(pq))={\rm GCD}(e,\phi(n))=1$ then you can find (by the so called Bezout identity) integers $r,s$ such that
$$
re+s\phi(n)=1.
$$
Thus you have
$$
m\equiv m^{re+s\phi(n)}\equiv c^r\bmod n
$$
and so you recover $m$ from $c$ proving its unicity.

In the above one uses the well known fact that $m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$ since the condition on $m$ implies that ${\rm GCD}(m,n)=1$ ($\phi$ is Euler's function, of course)

Comment: The well known fact is only true if m is coprime to n

Comment: @m_t_ Which is true in the OP's context (encryption).

Comment: @m_t_ : And indeed $m$ IS coprime to $n$, given the conditions. Anyway, I edited for better clarity.

Comment: @Bill: No, $m$ is not guaranteed to be co-prime to $n$: $m$ can take any value from $0$ to $n-1$. You need to treat the exceptions as a special case.

Comment: @TonyK In encrypton $m$ is always chosen to be coprime to $n$ (e.g. using padding schemes, etc).

Comment: @Bill: No it's not. RSA still works if $m$ is a multiple of $p$ or $q$, and no encryption scheme that I know of checks for this possibility.

Comment: @TonyK How do you thinks it works in that case?

Comment: @Bill: It works $\bmod p$, and it works $\bmod q$, even if one of $m \bmod p, m \bmod q$ is zero. So it works $\mod n=pq$.

Comment: @TonyK yes, in fact it does in this case (I was thinking about more general cases).

Comment: Guys, the OP asked the question for primes $p$ and $q$ bigger than $m$. In that case $m$ and $pq$ are certainly coprime.

Comment: @Andrea: Oh yes, you are right! But that was presumably a mistake :-)

Comment: @TonyK But in fact it is an assumption that works fine for practical purposes: if you use primes that are of the order of $10^{100}$, you can break up your original message in pieces that take, say, up to 90 digits each and encrypt them separately. The condition is thus met.

Comment: @TonyK e.g. it fails for nonsquarefree $m$, e.g. for $\,m=18\,$ we have $\,\phi(18)=6,\,$ and $\,{\rm mod}\ 6\!:\ e\equiv 5\equiv -1\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\, 1/e \equiv -1\equiv\color{#c00}5,\,$ but  $\,{\rm  mod}\ 18\!:\,\ (6^{\large 5})^{\large \color{#c00}5}\! \equiv 0,\,$ not $\,6.\ \ $

Comment: @Bill: I think you mean nonsquarefree $n$, which is impossible here.

Comment: @TonyK  Clearly $m$ is the modulus in my comment. My original comment may not have been clear to you, but it is correct, because I am referring to encryption schemes *in general*, which includes general moduli, as in my prior comment.

Comment: @Bill: Your comment said "Which is true in the OP's context (encryption)". This was wrong: $m$ does _not_ have to be co-prime to $n$ in the OP.s context (unless you take seriously the requirement that $m$ be less than $p$ and $q$). Just accept it and move on.

Comment: @AndreaMori I am quite comfortable with how $m$ can be recovered from $c$; the long proof I saw starts with Fermat's Little Theorem. However, you say that by recovering back $m$ from $c$, we prove its uniqueness. Is this generally true and why? hmm..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Raise $\ c\equiv m^{\large e}\pmod{pq}$ to power $\, k \equiv \dfrac{1}e\pmod{\phi(pq)}\ $ [it exists by $\,\gcd(e,\phi) = 1]$ 
which yields $\ c^k\equiv m,\ $  i.e. we can simply take the $e$'th root of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that $m$ can be extracted from $c$ is fine, but I was looking for a more direct proof. Here's how I started:

To prove that $c$ is unique to $m$ assume that the opposite is true, i.e. that two different $m$ can equal the same c:

$$m_1^e  \equiv m_2^e \mod n$$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are distinct.

By definition that means:

$(m_1^e - m_2^e) = kn$ where k is an integer not equal to zero.

This means that if there are two distinct $m$ producing same $c$, then  $(m_1^e - m_2^e)$ is divisible by $n$.

Here $n = pq$, $p, q$ are primes, $e$ is 3 or greater and co-prime with $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$, and $m$ is not divisible by $n$.

Can we show that the last statement above cannot be true for any $m_1$ and $m_2$? This would prove that $c$ is unique for any $m$ in the equation in the original posting.